# Can I make changes or fix bugs in my app after the App Showdown is over?

Tags: application-development, quickly, development

Is it allowed to make changes, like bug fixes after the deadline 09.07.2012 of the apps which are hosted on Launchpad for the Ubuntu App Showdown?
I did not updated anything with

```
quickly release
```

or

```
quickly submitubuntu
```

because I don't want to be disqualified for the contest.

I think it would be better to to allow (only) bug fixes, because I think the users of the apps would like to have a high quality software, with no bugs, available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your app after the deadline.

However, the judges will ignore those changes and use the packaged version you submitted before the deadline, so please hold off making any changes to the package unless you get an e-mail from the Ubuntu App Review Board asking you to do changes.

Comment: Thank you! I did the bug fixes locally on my computer and if you ask for them, I can upload the new version (code + package) to Launchpad. But the changes are not critical. I noted this also on the comment-field in the feedback-section on "Review history for <appname>" in the application upload portal. I hope I did the upload process right, because my app is in status "Pending review". I only uploaded the "Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt" containing the link to my ppa.